# Split a string by two strings

Tags: c#, .net

In Java you can easily do something like this :

```
String[] result = input.split("AAA|BBB");
```

Which means that if you have an input like this :

```
sssAAAvvvBBBuuu
```

the result will be like this :

```
sss
vvv
uuu
```

What is the best way to do this in c#, I know you can hardly split a string by another string in c# :

```
string[] result = input.Split(new string[] { "AAA" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

But how about splitting a string with two strings AAA and BBB ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just add another delimiter in array:

```
string[] result = input.Split(new string[] { "AAA", "BBB" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: and in C# you could simplify this to: var result = input.Split(new [] { "AAA", "BBB" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

Comment: @realbart, NO, that looses the redability

Comment: StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries is better option, if you dont need "AAA", "BBB"

Comment: @Rahul Not really, removing redundant typing information from arrays is pretty common.

Comment: @andy you will never get "AAA" and "BBB" even in the case of `StringSplitOptions.None` because it will not return delimiters.

Comment: you could also do this input.Split("AAA","BBB");

Answer (score 3):

You can use Regex:

```
string[] result = Regex.Split(input, "AAA|BBB");
```

Answer (score 0):

Ans is Below

```
 string test = "sssAAAvvvBBBuuu";

 string[] list = test.Split(new string[] { "AAA", "BBB" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

i hope you git answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
string str = "sssAAAvvvBBBuuu";
string[] separators = {"AAA", "BBB" };
string[] result = str.Trim().Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just create a function and call

```
public static string[] SplitString(string input)
{
    return Regex.Split(input, "AAA|BBB");
}

foreach (string word in SplitString("sssAAAvvvBBBuuu"))
{
    ........
    ........
}

Output: sss
        vvv
        uuu
```